# I cannot load images from my PC in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I am currently coding a game for a school project using Phaser. I am very new to Phaser and I know pretty much no JavaScript. I have looked up a lot of possible fixes online but none seem to do the trick for me. I attached my code in case I am missing something. When I change the directory of the image to an image link it works just fine but any images from my PC do not load.

```
var gameState = {}

function preload() {
  this.load.image('monkey', 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/jungle-thick/images/0/0c/Monky.png/revision/latest?cb=20190826180942');
  this.load.image('full', 'C:/Users/Public/Trash Monkey/Trash Monkey Website/Assets/Images')
  ;
}

function create() {
  var style = {
    fill: '#FFF',
    font: 'Bold 32px Arial'
  }



  gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  gameState.menuBox = this.add.rectangle(200, 250, 150, 80, 0xB5CF16);
  gameState.menu = this.add.text(147.5, 231, 'START', style);

  gameState.menuBox.setInteractive();

  gameState.menuBox.on('pointerup', function() {
    gameState.menuBox.x = 600
    gameState.menu.x = 600
    if(gameState.randomizer == 0) {
      gameState.monkey.x = 200;
      gameState.monkey.y = 0;
    }
    });
      gameState.randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random());
      if(gameState.randomizer == 0) {
        gameState.monkey = this.add.sprite(2000, 0, 'monkey');
        }
    gameState.fullHealth = this.add.sprite(300, 37.5, 'full');
}

function update() {
  if(gameState.randomizer == 0) {
    gameState.monkey.y += 3;
    if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
      gameState.monkey.x = 300;
    }
    if (gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
      gameState.monkey.x = 100;
    }
    if (gameState.cursors.up.isDown) {
      gameState.monkey.x = 200;
  }
    if (gameState.cursors.down.isDown) {
      gameState.monkey.y += 15;
  }
    if (gameState.monkey.y >= 500) {
      gameState.monkey.y = 0;
  }
  }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
  height: 500,
  backgroundColor: "#2191E8",
  parent: 'my-game',
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
    update
    }
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Comment: How are you running this code?  Does the URL in the browser say something like `file://c:/my/coool/project/index.html` or does it say `http://localhost:3000/mycoolproject/index.html`?  The `http://` vs `file://` matters.

Comment: I am running this through a file.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that you are trying to [load a local file from your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48580065/691711) rather than go through the server mechanism.

Comment: to add on to zero, browsers / js cannot just go looking through the users local file system, that would be a huge security risk. Instead you can use the FileReader API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader and upload the file you want to work with via the browser

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565296/cors-issue-with-html5-canvas-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust how you are developing.  The crux of the matter is that you are trying to load a file on your local computer through the browser's JavaScript context and that is plainly not allowed due to the security implications.

See:

- [Access to local files only work with local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48580065/691711)

The solution is to serve your project using a static server like Apache, NGINX, node.js, whatever.  It doesn't matter which one.  You don't need a complex solution.  You just need something that will serve your work on your local machine so that you can play nice with the Browser's security concerns.

The most straightforward way to deal with the need to use a static server is to use an integrated development environment (IDE) as many will do this for you.  Again it doesn't matter which one as long as it will serve your content.  [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) both have project templates for static projects and are fairly easy to set up.  [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has a Live Server extension that lets you serve a folder with just a right click.

Comment: I would recommend using the Live Server extension for VSCode. With that installed, it's as simple as opening your folder in it, right-clicking the file, and clicking "Open with Live Server".

Comment: @IceMetalPunk please feel free to edit or add to my answer.  I made this community wiki because it's a really loose answer to a concrete, but broad problem.  The simplest answer is "Don't use `file://`, host your assets over a server" but actually ***doing*** that has a lot of paths to the solution.